# Deny a folder to be viewed unless authenticated and access to a folder outside website root

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I am a little bit confused. I have a website (Apache) in root/website, in my main page there is an authentication form, when submitted the server check with LDAP if the user can get an authentication or not.

On success,the user should be redirected to a folder view of 'root/website/filestoview' and be able to navigate/download inside.

1. How can I achieve the redirection only if the user is authenticated and deny any attempt like `www.mysite.com/filestoview`?

   I tried htaccess:

   ```
   order deny,allow
   allow from localhost
   deny from all
   but didn't work.
   ```
2. How can I display the content (FTP ie. possibility to navigate/download) in a folder that is outside my root website? I tried from root `../../folder2` but it keep redirecting me to the main page.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Apache's authentication or some other custom script?

Comment: Other Custum Scripts. Authentification via a Database & session.

Comment: Well, you made me a bit confuse :) In this scenario you don't need .htaccess. If I understood the issue, you need to show a content outside of the public_html but only to authorized users. Check my answer - we can always change or improve if it doesn't provide a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Allow authorized users to browse and download files outside public_html

```
<?php 
// Allow authorized users to browse and download files outside public_html
// http://stackoverflow.com/users/1310701/hex494d49

if(is_user_authorized($user)){
    // at this point the user has been authorized
    // this is the protected directory; it is outside of public_html

    // this is the protected directory
    $home = $dir = '/home/user-root/member-area/';

    // prevent hacking :)
    if(isset($_GET["handle"]) && strpos($_GET["handle"], $home) !== false){
        if(is_dir($_GET["handle"])){
            $dir = $_GET["handle"] . "/";
        }else if(is_file($_GET["handle"])){
            $file = $_GET["handle"];
            // let user download the file
            download_file($file);
        }
     }

     // add <back> link if we are within some sub-directory
     echo ($dir != $home) ? "<a href='?handle=" . dirname($dir) ."'>back</a><br />" : "";

     // scan directory
     $entries = scandir($dir);
     $length = count($entries);
     for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
         if($entries[$i] != "." && $entries[$i] != "..") {
             echo "<a href='?handle=" . $dir . $entries[$i] . "'>" . $entries[$i] . "</a><br />";
         }
      }
}else{
    // user isn't authorized to view the content so 
    // redirect her/him to something entertaining :) 
    header("Location: https://disneyland.disney.go.com");
}

// -----
function is_user_authorized($user){
    // ... your authorization code
    return ($user) ? true : false;  
}

// -----
function download_file( $file_name ){
    if(!file_exists($file_name)) return false;
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; file_name = " . basename($file_name));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_name);
    exit;
}

?>
```

Further improvement: add filetype and filesize, encode/decode handles with base64, improve security

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are the best, this is almost what i am looking for. The only problem with this code is if i have a folder inside my folder than i am not able to explore it( return error).

Comment: @user3791570 You're welcome man :) I'll update the answer today later and drop you a message.

Comment: @user3791570 Check the updated version and let me know if you run in trouble :)